# "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." visual studio 2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I have a class library(C++) project in visual studio 2005, and want to debug this project using an application installed on the same PC. I have checked it was under debug and win32 platform.
But when I use the application to call one function in the class library, the breakpoint in the function can't be hit. The error is "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the library you are currently running does not match the code you have. I guess you did not compile and deploy the latest version of the code.

Comment: Hi, I have build the latest code of the class library before I right click debug in the project  @lolando

Comment: hmm. on PC there is a earlier dll installed, the application is written in C#, it only uses dllimport to import the dll file and call the function. I am not sure if the application is using the earlier dll installed on the PC @lolando

Comment: well, then you can check the timestamp or checksum

Comment: I fix the problem, it turns out to use the old dll installed in my PC instead of the new dll file. There are some problem when installing the new dll, the new dll doesn't repleace the old dll. Thanks @lolando

Comment: @Heidi: you are welcome, thank you too for confirming & providing feedback.